# My gas water heater's T&P relief valve is leaking. Can I safely close the heater's supply valve & leave the gas on?

Tags: plumbing, safety, valve

My gas water heater's pressure relief valve isn't sealing and releases ~3 gallons of water per hour outside the house. I'd like to shut the heater's water feed line OFF until I can buy and install a new valve. Is it safe to close  the heater's supply valve overnight w/o turning off the gas? Or would that be like a time bomb?

Comment: why do you need to leave the gas on overnight?

Comment: You may also need an expansion tank, depending on your water supply situation and why it's "not sealing" - it may be working correctly and sparing you a more dire problem, though in many cases they don't re-seal well once activated.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely best to turn off both the water and gas supply. Risking running your water heater dry is not worth it.

Comment: Leaving the gas or electric supply to a water heater on with the water off is a great way to end up needing a new water heater instead of a new relief valve, indeed.